# Manipulate UIPickerView to have single rows

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, rows

Does anyone understand how Apple manipulated the regular UIPickerView to look like the image below? Instead of two rows, I only need one in the middle. If anyone can point me in the right direction or show me a tutorial I'd really appreciate it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a narrow picker view.
Set it atop an image view.
Fill the image view with a screenshot of the picker background.

Comment: That's probably not the proper way of doing it, but where would I find a blank pickerview background?